# How to write a quine while keeping the code DRY?

Tags: c#, quine

A [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) is a program that prints its own source code without opening itself from the filesystem.

Here is an example of such a quine in C#:

```
class Q{static void Main(){var s="class Q{{static void Main(){{var s={1}{0}{1};System.Console.Write(s,s,'{1}');}}}}";System.Console.Write(s,s,'"');}}
```

This solution seems pretty messy and inelegant to me, though. It's a terrible program to maintain because whenever you change the source, you have to do it in two places, which is [a big programming no-no](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Is there a good way to write a quine in C# that doesn't violate the DRY principle?

Comment: Why on earth would you expect to be able to write a neat, elegant, quine in a conventional programming language?

Comment: @bmargulies Because you can write neat, elegant quines in other programming languages, such as Javascript. Is there a reason I should expect C# to be incapable of elegantly handling such a simple task?

Comment: Even if it is possible, I bet it still wouldn't be any more elegant. But that's subjective. I actually think the one you posted (which is pretty much the one everyone eventually comes up with when going for the shortest code) is pretty elegant in its way.